# How to update only one value that corresponds to a value from one row in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have the following table (called OptionRestriction):

```
 Feature_ID_1   OptionValue_1   value   Feature_ID_2    OptionValue_2   visible
      397             2           1         775              3            0
      404             3           1         403              5            0
      397             3           1         775              4            0
```

I use the table to update values in another table, called ConfigValue. Right now I have the following query to do this:

```
UPDATE       
ConfigValue
SET ConfigValue.Visible = Case When (select ConfigValue.value from 
                                        ConfigValue INNER JOIN OptionRestriction 
                                        ON ConfigValue.FeatureID = OptionRestriction.Feature_ID_1  
                                        where ConfigValue.ConfigurationID=66311 
                                        AND ConfigValue.FeatureID = OptionRestriction.Feature_ID_1 
                                        AND ConfigValue.OptionValue=OptionRestriction.OptionValue_1 
                                        AND ConfigValue.value=OptionRestriction.value)=1 Then 0 Else 1 End
FROM ConfigValue
INNER JOIN OptionRestriction ON ConfigValue.FeatureID = OptionRestriction.Feature_ID_2
WHERE
ConfigValue.OptionValue = OptionRestriction.OptionValue_2
AND ConfigValue.ConfigurationID = 66311
```

However, the problem with this query is that when I for instance want to update OptionValue 3 from feature 775 to visible = 0 (on the basis of setting value from feature 397 OptionValue 2 to 1) in the ConfigValue table, the query updates visible to 0 from both OptionValue 3 and 4 from feature 775, while I want it to only update visible from OptionValue 3 from feature 775 to 0. How can I achieve this?

UPDATE

The initial state of configvalue (when value from OptionValue from Feature 397 is 0) is:

```
ConfigurationID   Feature ID   OptionValue   Visible   Value
66311             397          2             1         0
```

And for featureID 775 option values 3 and 4:

```
ConfigurationID   Feature ID   OptionValue   Visible   Value
66311             775          3             1         0
66311             775          4             1         0
```

Currently when value from optionvalue 2 from feature id 397 is set to 1:

```
ConfigurationID   Feature ID   OptionValue   Visible   Value
66311             397          2             1         1
```

This happens (visible from both optionvalues from feature 775 is updated to 0):

```
ConfigurationID   Feature ID   OptionValue   Visible   Value
66311             775          3             0         0
66311             775          4             0         0
```

While I want this to happen (only update visible from optionvalue 3 from feature 775 to 0. Just like in the first row of OptionRestriction):

```
ConfigurationID   Feature ID   OptionValue   Visible   Value
66311             775          3             0         0
66311             775          4             1         0
```

When value from optionvalue 2 from feature id 397 is set to 0, visible from feature 775 optionvalue 3 should be updated back to 1. That is why I am using the CASE in my query now. So in fact, the value and visible columns are not needed in the OptionRestriction table.

Comment: If only `OptionValue2 = 3` should be used, just add this predicate to WHERE

Comment: Yeah, but the query should recognize the right value from the table. So the query should, for instance, be able to recognize that visible from OptionValue 3 from feature 775 should be set to 0, if the value from optionvalue 2 from feature 397 is set to 1.

Comment: Please show  ConfigValue initial state and desired update result

Comment: I have edited my initial question. Under Update you can see the initial and desired results

Comment: If you want to perform updates to a table conditionally based upon one of two columns (or sets of columns) in another table, I think you'll either need to restructure the source table to remove the (essentially) duplicated columns and shift them to be rows, or use dynamic SQL to structure your query to work from the correct column (or set of columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need

```
UPDATE cvUpd
SET cvUpd.visible = case cvFrom.value when 1 then 0 else 1 end 
FROM ConfigValue cvUpd
INNER JOIN OptionRestriction r ON cvUpd.ConfigurationID=66311
   AND cvUpd.FeatureID = r.Feature_ID_2
   AND cvUpd.OptionValue= r.OptionValue_2
INNER JOIN ConfigValue cvFrom ON cvFrom.FeatureID =r.Feature_ID_1  
   AND cvFrom.ConfigurationID = cvUpd.ConfigurationID 
   AND cvFrom.OptionValue=r.OptionValue_1 
   AND cvFrom.value=r.value
```

To check if the query joins proper rows just run

```
SELECT cvUpd.*, r.*, cvFrom.* , newval = case cvFrom.value when 1 then 0 else 1 end 
FROM ConfigValue cvUpd
INNER JOIN OptionRestriction r ON cvUpd.ConfigurationID=66311
   AND cvUpd.FeatureID = r.Feature_ID_2
   AND cvUpd.OptionValue= r.OptionValue_2
INNER JOIN ConfigValue cvFrom ON cvFrom.FeatureID =r.Feature_ID_1  
   AND cvFrom.ConfigurationID = cvUpd.ConfigurationID 
   AND cvFrom.OptionValue=r.OptionValue_1 
   AND cvFrom.value=r.value
```

Comment: Thanks voor the update query. It works partly. As stated at the end of my main question, the query should also update visible back to 1, when the related value of another optionvalue is 0. This is something that still does not work.

Comment: What the SELECT in the updated answer returns and what is wrong with it?

Comment: The select statement returns the headers only (ConfigurationID, FeatureID etc.). However, the update query runs fine, but does not update visible back to 1 if the value of a related optionvalue is 0. So for instance, when value from optionvalue 2 from feature id 397 is set back to 0, visible from feature 775 optionvalue 3 should be updated back to 1

Comment: It's hard to tell knowing so little about the whole thing, but my guess is `OptionRestriction` misses the rule for  0 . It should be a row with `value` = 0 to find the row in the `cvFrom` .

Comment: Thank you very much Serg! You were right. A row for value=0 needed to be added.